# What to do when a post belongs to 2 sites?

Tags: discussion

This does not happen frequently, but see for example:

[post on Signal Processing about wavelets](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13853/how-to-eliminate-border-effects-on-wavelet-denoising)
[same post on Quantative Finance about wavelets](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/9976/how-to-eliminate-border-effects-on-wavelet-denoising)

I'm sorry for this duplication, but is there a better way to put your post on 2 different sites, without this *stupid* duplication?

Comment: Cross-posting of exactly same question is not allowed.

Comment: **Don't cross post**. The question will be **most** suitable to one site. **Why** do you need it on two to begin with?

Comment: it's maybe 50.00001% more suitable in quant.. if you want, but I'd appreciate contributions of people from dsp

Comment: This is a Quantitative Finances question? How so?

Comment: @Oded still researching, but wavelet seem interesting to capture patterns, or to compress the number of values in a given time window without much loss (useful for machine learning)

Comment: Seems to me that you would have somewhat different questions to ask on the two sites, wouldn't you?  I mean, if there were immunology.stackexchange.com and medicine.stackexchange.com, I would ask a vaccine question on I as "how do naive cd8+ t-cells react to the protein in ..." and on medicine as "how is ... tolerated in children" or something like that - might be getting to the same place, but a different question nonetheless.

Comment: @Joe yes, I even had to phrase them differently, before I deleted dsp post. but It would have been a plus to be able to submit posts independantly of the site, the sites would just be views of whole SE content. with that I could have posted it with the right tags or 'super-tags' so as both dsp and quant can view and answer on it.

Comment: @cyril That's not how [SE] is intended to work though - each site is intended to be an independent community.